# Write an OCaml expression with the following type

Tags: ocaml

How can I write an Ocaml expression that matches this type (int -> int) -> (int -> int)?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so let's call this function F. F takes one argument — a function that takes an int and returns an int. When passed an argument of that type, F returns a function that takes an int and returns an int.

The simplest function that matches this type is the identity function.

Answer (score 1):

```
let f g = let _ = (g 0) + 1 in g
```